# Are unmodifiableMaps fail fast

Tags: java, collections

Is Map returned from Collections.unmodifiableMap Fail-Fast.

In other words does it throw `concurrentModificationException` while `iterating` if somebody else modifies the map with a "modifiable view" of the map

Comment: No i am just asking out of curiosity. As the documentation doesn't specify it.

Comment: Yes i could have done that, but isn't this community there for helping people and share experiences to save each other's time.

Comment: Trying it is not particularly clever, since you might end up relying on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the API doesn't define a behaviour it is implementation-dependent, i.e. it could vary depending on which Java runtime you are using.

For the Sun Java 6 runtime it looks as though the behaviour will be inherited from the Map you are wrapping. That's sensible behaviour, though, as I say, not guaranteed across implementations.

***Edit - test case for Sun Java 6:***

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;


public class TestUnmod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("a", "a");
        map.put("b", "b");
        map.put("c", "c");

        Map<String,String> unmod = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
        Iterator<String> it = unmod.values().iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        map.put("d", "d");
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
b
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:822)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1010)
    at TestUnmod.main(TestUnmod.java:18)
```

Comment: but @BorisPavlović 's answer implies that this might not be the case.

Comment: I think the sample code I just added clearly shows the exception happens (but, as I said, that is an implementation detail. It might be common sense but it is _not_ defined by the specification).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not fail-fast.

Although not especially mentioned, the API documentation states that "query operations on the returned map "read through" to the specified map, and attempts to modify the returned map ..., result in an UnsupportedOperationException". Since the unmodifiable map only delegates to the original map, all restrictions regarding use of the original map are also relevant for the unmodifiable wrapper.

Comment: So if the original map is fail-fast (as most are) then it is also fail-fast

Comment: According to your final sentence, the answer should then not be "no", but "if and only if the wrapped map is", right?

Comment: But the last answer gives a result that contrasts your answer as HashMap is fail-fast

Comment: @arne.b: If you wrap a red object in transparent plastic foil, is the foil then red, just because it looks red?

Comment: @sumit: I'm not sure which answer you are talking about, but HashMaps are not generally fail-fast.

Comment: here is the line in java 6 doc `The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast`

Comment: @jarnbjo Fail-fast is a statement about the behavior of the returned Map, not about its type. If color is the property we're concerned about, a red object in transparent plastic foil still behaves like a red object.

Comment: and what do you mean by "not generally"

Comment: @arne: I was obviously not clear enough: If you wrap a red object in a transparent wrapper, the wrapper is still transparent, even if it looks red. So, if you wrap a fail-fast map in a transparent wrapper, is the wrapper fail-fast, just because it shows a fail-fast behaviour?

Comment: the best effort fail-fast iterators is a separater issue. It doesn't mean that it is not fail-fast. So there is no ambiguity on that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated example which shows that the exception is thrown (thanks [@jarnbjo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180659/jarnbjo)):

```
final Map<Integer, String> original = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
final int capacity = 1000 * 100;
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
  original.put(i, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
final Map<Integer, String> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableMap(original);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
  executor.execute(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    Random r = new Random();
    int c = original.size();
    for (int i = c; i < c + 1000; i++) {
    original.put(i, UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    }
  }
  });

  executor.execute(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : unmodifiable.entrySet()) {
    sb.append(entry.getValue()).append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println("sb.toString().length() = " + sb.toString().length());
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the effort and i think it must be right, but everyone here seems to be contradicting your answer.

Comment: @Boris: Your code is only replacing already existing values, which is supported by the HashMap implementation. For the iterator to fail, you have to make a structural change to the map, e.g. add or remove an entry.

Comment: for k=0 it is adding new values..but for k=1 to 4 it is replacing values, may be first iteration of modifiable is over before the unmodifiable map iteration begins